# C# adding/subtracting/multiplying/dividing different items in listbox based on first character of item

Tags: c#, math, textbox, listbox

I have a program at the moment that adds items to a list box, the items consist of a character (+,-,*,/) followed by numbers. I have been attempting to get my program to recognize the first character of the item in the list box and doing the math appropriately all day, but I just cannot seem to get it right. Im not even sure what code I should be using.

Just to make it a little more clear

Items get entered into a textbox called `txtCalculation` in this sort of format "+34233", that value is then added into the list box `lstDisplay` so after 5 items it should look like this.

```
+2
+4
/2
-1
+5
*3
total = 21
```

I would like to find a way to make the program go through the list and do the math and then add it as a final item to the list as shown above. I already have the code to add the numbers to the list, but I would really appreciate if anyone could spare some time to explain to me how I would go about doing something like this.

Code for adding items to list box:

```
if (txtCalculation.Text.Length > 1)
        {
            string Number = txtCalculation.Text;
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                try
                {
                    lstDisplay.Items.Add(Number);
                    txtCalculation.Text = "";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the try block something like

```
switch (line[0])
{
    case '+':
        num += Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(1));
        break;
    case '-':
        num -= Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(1));
        break;
}
```

where line is the current line and num is your running total. The substring will make a new string by including everything except the first character in line. The 1 indicates to start from the second character because strings are 0 indexed (as are most things in C#).

Comment: This seems very likely to work, the only problem is I am still a newbie and I'm unsure of how to actually implement the restOfLine. I figure that I am supposed to use Substring and convert.ToInt32, but I think the main problem I really was having is understand how to use them.